# Face API - create a person using a faceid list

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Face.detect() to check if there are faces on a bunch of image files. After this, I collect the detected faceIds and call Face.group() to obtain groups of faces, which will group the faces by person.

Then I would like to create Persons using these lists of faceIds, but can't find the correct API method to do so. I can only create Person faces by re-uploading the images.

Is there a way to create Person (faces) using the previously obtained faceIds returned by Face.detect()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the API today.  Incidentally, a [feature request](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430315-face/suggestions/13869804-adding-faces-for-person-and-face-lists-should-take) for this exists already, and you may want to upvote/comment there.